# How can I run unit tests without calling application callback

Tags: unit-testing, elixir

My application callback start Supervisor that conflicts with unit tests.

With that callback I am getting something like `{:error, {:already_started, #PID<0.258.0>}}` when I try to run unit test because my processes are already started.

Can I execute Application callback only for `:dev` and  `:prod`, keeping `:test` environment clean of startup code?

I am looking for something like this:

```
def application do
[
  applications: [:logger],
  mod: {MyApplication, [], only: [:dev, :prod]} 
]
```

`only: [:dev, :prod]` - this is missing piece

Comment: Did you mean `only: [:dev, :prod]`?

Comment: @Dogbert You are right. Will fix the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this is the correct way to handle testing in this case, but here's how you can do what you're asking for:

In `mix.exs`:

```
def application do
  rest = if(Mix.env == :test, do: [], else: [mod: {MyApp, []}])
  [applications: [:logger]] ++ rest
end
```

For the demo below, I added the following to `MyApp.start/2`:

```
IO.puts "starting app..."
```

Demo:

```
$ MIX_ENV=dev mix
starting app...
$ MIX_ENV=prod mix
starting app...
$ MIX_ENV=test mix # no output
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to kill that process before the test suite runs. For example you could do something like the below:

```
setup do
  Process.exit(pid, :kill)
end

test "do something..." do
  assert 1 == 1
end
```

This will ensure that before the test is run, that process is already killed.

Comment: That definitely will work but I would like to avoid setting up every test with cleaning code. Thanks for reply though.